# Why won't my nav drop down menu center on the page?

Tags: html, css

I am using a horizontal drop down navigation bar, and the bar itself is centered within the left site of the site, however I want it to be centered within the entire page. How can I get this to the very center? Here is my css/html code:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    max-height:10500;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#navMenu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navMenu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:27px;
}

#navMenu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#000;
}

#navMenu li a {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"futura condensed medium", futura, arial;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
}

#navMenu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:30px;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}

#navMenu li:hover {
    background:#F66;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background:#b24747;
}

#navMenu a:hover {
    color:#000;
}

.clearFloat {
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

---

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navMenu">

<ul>
<li><a href="#">D4G</a>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>


</ul> <!--end inner UL div-->

</li> <!--end main LI div-->
</ul> <!--end main UL div-->

<ul>
<li><a href="#">EVENTS</a>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>


</ul> <!--end inner UL div-->

</li> <!--end main LI div-->
</ul> <!--end main UL div-->

<ul>
<li><a href="#">SIGN ME UP</a>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>


</ul> <!--end inner UL div-->

</li> <!--end main LI div-->
</ul> <!--end main UL div-->

<ul>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>


</ul> <!--end inner UL div-->

</li> <!--end main LI div-->
</ul> <!--end main UL div-->
<br class="clearFloat"/>

</div> <!--end navMenu div-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
#navMenu {
    width: 200px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    padding : 0;
    line-height : 27px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that de-stacks the nav and makes the drop down menu vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: Then just give the width bigger value .. 400px maybe?

Comment: That did help somewhat thank you, it is just a matter of what is the magic number!

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what You want. :)

> I've put changes demo online here: Edit fiddle - JSFiddle http://goo.gl/9o8hOK

NOTE: I've marked with a (+) plus sign what was changed.

```
#navMenu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  + text-align: center;
}
#navMenu ul {
  + text-align: left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:27px;
  + display: inline-block;
}
```

Enjoy and good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to remove `float: left` from `li` elements and add `display: inline-block` to `ul` and `li` elements and also `text-align: center` to main wrapper `#navMenu`:

```css
#wrapper {
    max-height:10500;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#navMenu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}
#navMenu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:27px;
    display: inline-block;/*add display inline block*/
}
#navMenu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;/*add display inline block*/
    position:relative;
    background-color:#000;
}
#navMenu li a {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"futura condensed medium", futura, arial;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
}
#navMenu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:30px;
    left: 0;/*add left 0 to align properly*/
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}
#navMenu li:hover {
    background:#F66;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background:#b24747;
}
#navMenu a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
.clearFloat {
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navMenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">D4G</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--end inner UL div-->
      </li>
      <!--end main LI div-->
    </ul>
    <!--end main UL div-->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--end inner UL div-->
      </li>
      <!--end main LI div-->
    </ul>
    <!--end main UL div-->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">SIGN ME UP</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--end inner UL div-->
      </li>
      <!--end main LI div-->
    </ul>
    <!--end main UL div-->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--end inner UL div-->
      </li>
      <!--end main LI div-->
    </ul>
    <!--end main UL div-->
    <br class="clearFloat" />
  </div>
  <!--end navMenu div-->
</div>
```

Fix: `Add left: 0` to `#navMenu ul ul` to sub menus align properly.